# BlackBerry 10 - Dialog Box

Tags: c++, qt, blackberry-10, cascade

I m developing one app for contact reading . In contact adding page I have created some textfields like first name n last name , phone number etc. And I have created one ActionItem to save or create contact . like this

```
acceptAction: ActionItem {
        title: (_contactRead.contactEditor.mode == ContactEditor.CreateMode ? qsTr ("Create" ) : qsTr ("Save"))

        onTriggered: {
            _contactRead.contactEditor.saveContact()

            navigationPane.pop()
        }
    }
```

I want to display pop up (dialog box or toast) when we click on save or create contact. I tried to add open() in onTriggered but confused how and where to create dialog box.

Please help me out....

Comment: check my solution. i think it will help you for display alert notification

Answer (score 1):

use --> alert(tr("contact saved"));

refer following sample

-----------qml--------------

```
 Button {
            horizontalAlignment: HorizontalAlignment.Center

            text: qsTr("Update")

            onClicked: {
                _app.updateRecord(idUpdateTextField.text, firstNameUpdateTextField.text, lastNameUpdateTextField.text);
            }
        }
```

-----------------cpp file-------------------

```
bool App::updateRecord(const QString &customerID, const QString &firstName, const QString &lastName)
{


    bool intConversionGood = false;
    const int customerIDKey = customerID.toInt(&intConversionGood);
    if (!intConversionGood) {
        alert(tr("You must provide valid integer key."));
        return false;
    }


    QSqlDatabase database = QSqlDatabase::database();

    QSqlQuery query(database);
    const QString sqlCommand = "UPDATE customers "
                               "    SET firstName = :firstName, lastName = :lastName"
                               "    WHERE customerID = :customerID";
    query.prepare(sqlCommand);
    query.bindValue(":firstName", firstName);
    query.bindValue(":lastName", lastName);
    query.bindValue(":customerID", customerIDKey);


    bool updated = false;
    if (query.exec()) {

        if (query.numRowsAffected() > 0) {
            alert(tr("Customer with id=%1 was updated.").arg(customerID));
            updated = true;
        } else {
            alert(tr("Customer with id=%1 was not found.").arg(customerID));
        }
    } else {
        alert(tr("SQL error: %1").arg(query.lastError().text()));
    }


    database.close();

    return updated;
}
```

[For sample app from here](https://github.com/blackberry/Cascades-Samples/tree/master/databasecrud)